# No package found when deploying an Asp.Net Core application to Azure using Azure DevOps

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following Publish and Deploy tasks in Azure DevOps:

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  azureSubscription: 'subscription'
  azureAppType: 'Web App on Windows'
  webAppName: 'webapp'

steps:

# Other tasks

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  inputs:
    package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/MyProj.zip
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    appType: '$(azureAppType)'
    webAppName: '$(webAppName)'
```

The publish tasks succeeds but I get the error on the Deploy task:

```
[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/MyProj.zip
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Review your YAML:

You publish with the following parameters:
`--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

You try to deploy from **a completely different location**: 
`package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/MyProj.zip`

Try deploying `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/MyProj.zip`.

Comment: I tried and I keep getting the same error ... Any idea?

Comment: If you're getting the **same** error, then you didn't update the YAML file. `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` would be a path like `/home/vsts/work/1/a/`. If you're getting *that* as the path, then you need to look at your build output to see what the actual path to the published file is.